# How to pass a variables for refetchQueries in Apollo

Tags: reactjs, apollo

I am not sure what the best practice is to pass `variables` in `refetchQueries` options. In below example the variables is `{id: this.props.item.id}`

But passing `this.props.item.id` returned an **error** since `MyComponent` is not yet instantiated hence `this.props` is undefined.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    item: state.item
  };
}

MyComponent = connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(
  MyComponent
);

MyComponent = graphql(createItemImage, {
  name: "createItemImage",
  options: {
    refetchQueries: [
      {
        query: getEntity,
        variables: { id: this.props.item.id }
      }
    ]
  }
  })(MyComponent);
```

The `id` value will only be available during runtime.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 23):

This is what finally works, refer to `ownProps` and the order (`connect` statement should be **after** the `graphql` statement)

```
MyComponent = graphql(createItemImage, {
  name: "createItemImage",
  options: ownProps => ({
    refetchQueries: [
      {
        query: getEntity,
        variables: { id: ownProps.item.id }
      }
    ]
  })
})(MyComponent);

MyComponent = connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(
  MyComponent
);
```

Comment: The documentation for the `{ query, variables }` object is at https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#refetchqueries

Answer (score 4):

You  need to explicitly pass item.id variable to the component. Therefore add in function a variable naming id

```
 MyComponent = graphql(createItemImage, {
  name: "createItemImage",
  options: {
    refetchQueries: [
      {
        query: getEntity,
        variables: { id: id }
      }
    ]
  }
})(MyComponent, id);

export default MyComponent
```

Then when calling the component use the following syntax

```
<MyComponent id={this.props.item.id}>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: sorry but this is not the problem. I understood I need to pass `item={id: 123}` in calling MyComponent e.g. `<MyComponent item={id:123}/>`... but it is failing at compiled time with below error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'item' of undefined` because `this.props` is undefined

Comment: Sorry! My bad i used this.props inside component, we must use id directly here in this case. No need to use it via this.props. Have updated the code. Note: since we are not extending our component from React , the component will not receive life cycle function and props variable